# May I use "to have the moves" to generally mean "to have the competence in something"?

Tags: phrase-usage

*To have the moves* is used to mean that somebody memorized, and gained competence in, the movements required for a dance.

Can I use it to generally mean that somebody gained competence in something that is not dance or a sport? Would that be understood, or would native English speakers be confused by what I say?

Comment: It is a figurative slang expression meaning that someone is especially skilled at something. It could be card-sharking, basketball, selling used cars,  getting dates. But probably not corporate finance or eye surgery, unless the speaker was being intentionally humorous.  When you "have the moves" you are an *impressive* even *dazzling* practitioner or performer.

Comment: I can't actually say *I have the moves* is **dated** (though I seem to have been tired of it for years). But to me it's at least **quaint** - on a par with *I'm a dab hand* or *I know my onions*. Such terms are best avoided unless you've already heard them being used by the people you're conversing with.

Comment: I think the examples would have helped users visualize what you meant, especially learners, but each to his own.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How can `I have the moves to _____` be of any help?

Comment: "*I have the moves to win that competition*"? What about the second example, which comes from Oxford Dictionaries? And I've explained, it helps learners visualize the sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you are going to add examples, give at least a complete example, without omitted parts. Also, the example should not change the meaning of the question. If I am asking when I can use a phrase, and then you add an example showing the phrase is not used just for dance or sports, my question doesn't make sense anymore, doesn't it?

Comment: A competition doesn't have to be a dance or a sport competition, e.g. a *poetry competition*.  It also showed that "to have the moves" is usually followed by the infinitive. And the "to ___" blank you could have filled in yourself. What type of competence are you referring to?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That shows exactly my point. Do I ask _Can I use it to generally mean that somebody gained competence in something that is not dance or a sport?_ showing an example where the phrase is used for something that is not dance or a sport? It would be like asking a question and answering it in the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, "to have the moves" is actually slightly derogatory. It makes the subject seem to be slick, or even arrogant. Perhaps that comes from the idiom "to put the move on someone", meaning to approach them sexually, but if someone "has the moves" in anything *other* than dance, to me they are not so much competent (although that is implied), but almost overbearing about it.